# How can i remove manifest merge errors

Tags: android, android-manifest, androidx

I added MaterialAlertDialog to my project which was not using androidx. This caused errors during the next build. So i removed the 'implementation' statement from app level build gradle. But still i am having manifest merge error when i try to build my project.

This is the error i get during build time

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-152:19 to override.

So far i have tried the following solutions,Close and reload my project. Do a clean and rebuild .delete the .gradle and .idea folders in my project and build it again

These are the dependencies in my project

```
    dependencies 
    {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${android_support_version}"
        implementation "com.android.support:design:${android_support_version}"
        implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
        implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
        implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
        implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }

        implementation "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:${circle_imageview}"
        implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glide_version}"
        implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${android_support_version}"
        implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${android_support_version}"
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofit_service_version}"
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofit_gson_convertor}"
        implementation "com.clough.android.androiddbviewer:androiddbviewer:${dbviewer_version}"
        implementation "com.android.support:multidex:${multidex_version}"
        implementation "com.github.crosswall:Android-Coverflow:${viewPager_version}"
        implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0"
        implementation project(':sdkui')
        implementation 'com.github.ronaldsmartin:Material-ViewPagerIndicator:1.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You are using firebase libraries which require androidx migration.

Comment: Did you try: Clean and Rebuild on Android Studio?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti My project was working fine until i tried adding the Dependency for MaterialAlertDialog. So i am not sure if firebase is cauing this issue.

Comment: @DeepakJanardhanan Also the Material Components Library requires [androidx libraries](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#new-namespace-and-androidx).

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  what you said was correct. It was the Firebase that caused the issue. I reduced it to 17.3.4 and the build was successful.

Comment: @DeepakJanardhanan You can also check the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) of firebase and google play services. Starting from these versions the androidx migration is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering this just to specify the step it took to clear my issue.

1. I removed the gradle dependency for the MaterialDesign.
2. The cashe issue was solved by doing  File-> Invalidate Cache & restart

Since Firebase was changed to ver 20 before restart the issue persisted.

Reduced Firebase version to 17.3.4 this fixed everything.

Comment: My thanks to  Gabriele Mariotti  whose comment under my question allowed me to solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines in your Manifest file.

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

**Manifest File**

```
<application
 android:allowBackup="false"
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
 android:supportsRtl="false"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
 tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
 android:appComponentFactory="whateverString">
```

Comment: this did not work. It simply caused additional errors to occur. I would like to mention that i am not trying to convert to androidx but simply removing the single gradle entry that used androidx.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

If you have any Maven dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX namespace, the Android Studio build system also migrates those dependencies for you when you set the following two flags to true in your gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Add these lines in your Manifest file in Application TAG.

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

Comment: This is a hack and doesn't solve the core issue. Instead, make sure you update all libraries. I looked at the `build.gradle` and in 0.5 seconds I found `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` which isn't allowed in AndroidX. This and other outdated libraries should be removed or replaced.

Comment: Updating code with the latest version is always better way

Comment: Surpressing an error message using `tools:replace` combined with `android:appComponentFactory` is a hack. You aren't solving the core issue, you are only _applying a temporary band aid to a large gaping wound_. I found a nice definition here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73334/what-is-a-hack/73335#73335 .